# How to open a Kendo Grid in a Kendo Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a grid with a custom command:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OfficeTracker.ViewModels.OffViewModel>()
.Name("OffGrid")
columns.Command(command =>
{ 
      command.Custom("OfficeLocations").SendDataKeys(true).Click("openOfficeLocations");
}); ...
```

When the button is clicked, It should open another grid in a pop up window.

Here is the KendoWindow:

```
@{Html.Kendo().Window().Name("OffDetails")
.Title("Office Details")
.Visible(false)
.Modal(true)
.Draggable(true)
.Visible(false)
.Modal(true)
.Draggable(true)
.Content(@<text> @showGrid(6470) </text>)
}
```

I created a helper to hold the grid (it sends the officeID to the Controller):

```
@helper showGrid(int officeID)
{ 
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OfficeTracker.ViewModels.LocViewModel>()
       .Name("LocGrid")
       .Columns(columns =>
          { ...
}
```

Then this JavaScript function:

```
function openOfficeLocations(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var officeid = dataItem.OfficeID;
    var wnd = $("#OfficeDetails").data("kendoWindow");

    //wnd.content(wnd.content(@<text> @showWCGrid(officeid) </text>));

    wnd.center().open();
    wnd.refresh();
}
```

My problem is with the "wnd.content" line. If I don't include it, the grid opens when I click on the "OfficeLocations" button, but because I have hard coded the officeid, it always opens the same record.  If I include the "wnd.content" line, it throws an error.  I don't know if this needs to be formatted a certain way or what the problem is.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  This is kind of like a detail window, but I need to have two buttons.